Exception calling "AutodiscoverUrl" with "1" argument(s): "The Autodiscover service couldn't be located."

# Load the EWS Managed API assembly

Add-Type -Path "\<path\>Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"

# Define the sender email address

$senderAddress = "XXX"

# Create Exchange Service object

$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService -ArgumentList "Exchange2013"
$service.UseDefaultCredentials= "True"

# Autodiscover URL using sender address and validation callback

$service.AutodiscoverUrl($senderAddress)
$email = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage -ArgumentList $service
$email.Subject = "Test Email"
$email.Body = "This is a test email sen."
$email.ToRecipients.Add("XXX")

# Send and save a copy

$email.SendAndSaveCopy()

when I am running above script with powershell ise  and using specific user credential then run above script it is working and getting mail. where I used invoke command using same credential and try to run script then I am getting Exception calling "AutodiscoverUrl" with "1" argument(s): "The Autodiscover service couldn't be located." error
using invoke command run script and get mail
